# Edit back indicator margin in support action bar on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

In my app i set a support action bar in toolbar and everything is OK .
My question is how can i edit the back indicator button and reduce the space between icon and my image as logo as shown in below picture ??

[image]

And this is my function for creating this toolbar

```
private fun initToolbar(){
        setSupportActionBar(binding.PrivateActivityToolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)

        if (intent.getStringExtra("toFullname") !== null){
            supportActionBar?.title = intent.getStringExtra("toFullname")
        }else{
            supportActionBar?.title = toUsername
        }
        supportActionBar?.subtitle = "Online"

        Glide.with(this)
            .asDrawable()
            .load(if (profilePic == "" || profilePic == null){
                R.drawable.defaultprofile
            }else{
                MyInternalStorage(this).getProfilePic(profilePic!!)
            })
            .centerCrop()
            .circleCrop()
            .override(140,140)
            .into(object : CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
                override fun onResourceReady( resource: Drawable,  transition: Transition<in Drawable>? ) {
                    supportActionBar?.setLogo(resource)
                }

                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                    supportActionBar?.setIcon(placeholder)
                    //supportActionBar?.setLogo(placeholder)
                }

            })
    }
```

Comment: I suppose you're using the icon and the text in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout `, am I correct? Please add the corrent code of your `Toolbar` or whatever that is.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท No , I use predefined toolbar as supportActionBar . Also i add my function in question